# Retrieving image from NSData

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdata

I have a view controller that allows me to add a name, image, and date..the name and date are sent back to the table view controller and displayed..I then have a edit view controller that shows when a populated cell is clicked...

my save method:

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender {
  NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageview.image);
  [self.currentPlayer setValue:imageData forkey:@"playerPic"];

 [self.delegate addPlayerViewControllerDidSave];
}
```

my delegate is calling the save:&error so i wont paste that code

I believe this is working but my question is how do I have that image display on the edit view controller

my name and date information is passing but not the image

I have a UIImageView and I am attempting something like that but I understand those are two different pointer types and wont work

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
 firstnameTextField.text = [self.currentPlayer playerName];
 editImage.image = [self.currentPlayer playerPic];

 }
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a UIImage from your NSData object as follows:

```
[UIImage imageWithData:[self.currentPlayer playerPic]]
```